# Retrofit 2 returns "null". The same query in Postman works fine

Tags: android, retrofit2

I am facing a weird behaviour. I have a query that should return json.
This is my interface:

```
public interface SubjectService {
    @POST("/a/query/to/json?mobile=1")
    Observable<SubjectRaw> getSubject(@Query("subjId") Integer subjId);
}
```

Here I call it:

```
@Override
public Observable<SubjectRaw> loadData(Integer gcourse) {
    return subjectService.getSubject(gcourse).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread());
}
```

This is my ServiceGenerator class:

```
public class ServiceGenerator {



private static Retrofit.Builder builder =
        new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create());

public static <S> S createService(Class<S> serviceClass, String authString) {
    HttpLoggingInterceptor interceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
    interceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
    OkHttpClient.Builder httpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder();
    httpClient.addInterceptor(interceptor);
    httpClient.addInterceptor(chain -> {
        Request request = chain.request()
                .newBuilder()
                .addHeader("Authorization", " Basic " + authString).build();
        return chain.proceed(request);
    });
    Retrofit retrofit = builder.client(httpClient.build()).build();
    return retrofit.create(serviceClass);
}

}
```

I pass a Basic Authorization String to retrofit as well. For other queries it works fine, but for this I get **null**. 
The same request in Postman works just fine:
[image]
What am I missing here?

Here is output from Logging-Interceptor:

```
D/OkHttp: <-- 200  https://a/query/to/json?mobile=1&subjId=37622 (2025m
D/OkHttp: date: Fri, 31 Mar 2017 07:39:02 GMT
D/OkHttp: content-type: application/json
D/OkHttp: content-length: 4
D/OkHttp: set-cookie: __cfduid=da4b9463541e1542b6e983bc2b075652e1490945942; expires=Sat, 31-M
D/OkHttp: set-cookie: PHPSESSID=1a75rhfcvliejadv01rvmacpd0; path=/
D/OkHttp: expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
D/OkHttp: cache-control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate
D/OkHttp: pragma: no-cache
D/OkHttp: x-uversion: 2.1.2
D/OkHttp: server: cloudflare-nginx
D/OkHttp: cf-ray: 3481a70a9ea17600-ARN
D/OkHttp: null
D/OkHttp: <-- END HTTP (4-byte body)
```

Comment: Do you get the response after being authorized by the server, or it doesn't require authorization ?

Comment: Try to use stetho http://facebook.github.io/stetho/ for network inspection. Or Okhttp Logging Interceptor https://github.com/square/okhttp/tree/master/okhttp-logging-interceptor

Comment: I added ServiceGenerator method. I pass authorization token there. So I dont need to get response confirming authorization, it justs sends response. And I am already using logging-interceptor.

Comment: Have you just removed base_url? https://a/query/to/json?mobile=1&subjId=37622

Comment: Can you show the `builder` object use to create the `retrofit` object ?

Comment: Of course not. Base url is in the HttpClient itself. Look at the ServiceGenerator for builder.

Comment: try decorating your service interface method(getSubject) with @FormUrlEncoded

Comment: Wow, it worked indeed. If you could elaborate on that and post an answer, it would be great. Thank you a lot)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Yordan provided solution

> try decorating your service interface method(getSubject) with @FormUrlEncoded

As he did not post answer, I am just posting it here for anyone that might face the same problem. 
Credit for answer goes to @Yordan.